# Locating database file

Tags: reactjs, sqlite, react-native

I am working with sqlite and react native .I am having problem in locating the database file which is created after this command **var db = SQLite.openDatabase({name:'empRecordData.sqlite'})**.I want to know where this empRecordData.sqlite file is created.I looked everywhere in the project folder but found nothing.please help me out

Comment: What "project folder" - are you using an IDE? Have you tried a search command like `find` on Unix/Linux? Windows has file/directory search functions, too. What's the working directory of your program, have you looked there?

Comment: yes i am usin visual code.I tried to search globally on the system but was not able to locate the file

Comment: Start the app in debug mode, and look for the string like `Opening db in mode READ_WRITE, full path: ...` in the developer console. It should show the full path there.

Comment: you mean to say that i have to do a remote js debugging and in the console should write "Opening db in mode READ_WRITE, full path: ..." ???

Comment: Prasun Pal ,i tried it but not able to find the file